# How can I make background fades when a custom component is in focus in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I created a custom component that is a s:SkinnableContainer. I want the background and other items to fade out when this component is visible. Something similar to what happens when calling Alert.show(..) so the Alert box is in focus and everything else is faded out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set alpha of container of the background to less than 1.

alternatively use custom component as a popup using PopupManager

Comment: The same thing I'm having with as I explained in the comment in the answer by @Robusto. What do you suggest doing?

Comment: I used something similar I just made another Canvas part of the component that extends all around the screen and put the background Alpha for it less than 1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to blur everything in a container, use something like:

```
<mx:BlurFilter id="myBlur" blurX="3" blurY="3" quality="3" />
```

or in AS3

```
private function blurObj(cont:Container) : void {
  var filters:Array = cont.filters;
  var bf:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(3,3,3);
  filters.push(bf);
  cont.filters = filters;
}
```

Change the values of the BlurFilter properties (or constructor args) to values that suit you.

Comment: Thanks. You idea worked. The issue I'm having is that I have multiple objects and I want to blur everything except the one being in focus. You idea seem to blur everything. Any suggestions?